# mysql count of assigned ID occurences in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty sure there is an easier way to structure this. I am attempting to get a fax number and unit ID from one table, then get the number of times a unique user ID appears tied to that unit ID in two subsequent tables.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT db.table.faxnum, db.table.idnum, c.*, d.*
FROM db.table
LEFT JOIN ( select db.comments.userid, count(*) as comments
    FROM db.comments
    WHERE db.comments.date_submit >= '2016-02-26'
    AND db.comments.date_submit <= '2016-02-28'
    AND db.comments.idnum='1234' 
    group by db.comments.userid) as c
  ON db.table.idnum = '1234'
LEFT JOIN ( select db.edits.editid, count(*) as edits
    FROM db.edits
    WHERE db.edits.date_submit >= '2016-02-26'
    AND db.edits.date_submit <= '2016-02-28'
    AND db.edits.idnum='1234' 
    group by db.edits.editid) as d
  ON db.table.idnum = '1234'
WHERE db.table.didnum = '1234'
```

If I run the query with a single join, I get 1 row for each user with either the number of comments or the number of edits (Depending on which join) I attach. So if I run it with just the comments join subquery, I get back:

```
+-------+-------+--------+----------+
| Faxnum| Idnum | Userid | Comments |
+-------+-------+--------+----------+
|5551212| 1234  |   5    |    4     |
|5551212| 1234  |  10    |   12     |
|5551212| 1234  |  15    |    9     |
+-------+-------+--------+----------+
```

If I use both joins, I get 25 rows back, where only 5 match the desired output. (I shortened the output for demonstration in this case)

```
+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| Faxnum| Idnum | Userid | Comments | Userid | Edits  |
+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|5551212| 1234  |   5    |    4     |   5    |   22   | *
|5551212| 1234  |  10    |   12     |  10    |   11   |
|5551212| 1234  |  15    |    9     |  15    |   18   |
|5551212| 1234  |   5    |    4     |   5    |   22   |
|5551212| 1234  |  10    |   12     |  10    |   11   | *
|5551212| 1234  |  15    |    9     |  15    |   18   |
|5551212| 1234  |   5    |    4     |   5    |   22   |
|5551212| 1234  |  10    |   12     |  10    |   11   |
|5551212| 1234  |  15    |    9     |  15    |   18   | *
+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

The * represents the correct/desired row for each unique user ID (User ID's are assigned by IDnum).

How can I restructure the query to remove the extraneous result rows? (In the table example, it would be rows 2-4 and 6-8).

Example desired result:

```
+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| Faxnum| Idnum | Userid | Comments | Userid | Edits  |
+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|5551212| 1234  |   5    |    4     |   5    |   22   | 
|5551212| 1234  |  10    |   12     |  10    |   11   | 
|5551212| 1234  |  15    |    9     |  15    |   18   | 
+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the tables and some sample data?  Part of the problem I'm seeing immediately is you aren't really joining your `db.table` to the tables in the subqueries - do you have an id or something you can join those table on?

Comment: @bluefeet - Not really. These are clipper DBF's originally and  at the time were simply replicated into mysql format. The idnum is the commonality between the three tables. There is a unique ID in the mysql table but they are not related to each other through that.

Comment: It looks like you have a Cartesian Product in your query. I'm assuming that there are more columns that are not being shown? If  you notice, it's repeating the same sets of rows 3 times. If you're selecting all the items in tables c and d, then there's probably some column that's different between the three occurrences.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but on your `on` for table d, you could add d.userid = c.userid, and that might fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is you are not actually joining your outer `db.table` with your subqueries, so while you have `LEFT JOIN` written you aren't actually doing a join. You are creating a `CROSS JOIN` or cartesian type of result giving you so many rows in the final result.

You need to JOIN the `db.table` to the subqueries **and** it appears that you need to JOIN the subqueries to each other via the `userid`.  I'd suggest making a few minor changes to the query to be:

```
SELECT db.table.faxnum, db.table.idnum, 
  c.userid, c.comments, 
  d.editid, d.edits
FROM db.table
LEFT JOIN 
( 
  select db.comments.grpnum, db.comments.userid, count(*) as comments
  FROM db.comments
  WHERE db.comments.date_submit >= '2016-02-26'
    AND db.comments.date_submit <= '2016-02-28'
    AND db.comments.grpnum='1234' 
  group by db.comments.grpnum, db.comments.userid
) as c
  ON db.table.idnum = c.grpnum
LEFT JOIN 
( 
  select db.edits.grpnum, db.edits.editid, count(*) as edits
  FROM db.edits
  WHERE db.edits.date_submit >= '2016-02-26'
    AND db.edits.date_submit <= '2016-02-28'
    AND db.edits.grpnum='1234' 
  group by db.edits.grpnum, db.edits.editid
) as d
  ON db.table.idnum = d.grpnum
  AND c.userid = d.editid
WHERE db.table.idnum = '1234';
```

Without seeing your full table structure, I'm basing this off of your end result above - [here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4459a/7). But if you fix the joining problems, you should be able to return the rows you need.